# How to add parse dependency in android empty project?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Hey I want to add parse as backend (https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-gu6judefvlbxg) in my android project dependencies, I had EC2 instance, parse server url , masterKey , ... (things which will require to connect with parse server as said in udemy course tutorial, which I am following.)

I checked many online tutorials and blogs but most of them are outdated, can anyone help to add parse dependencies to my project?

Comment: Please try this guide: https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/parse-android-sdk